# Looping with different variables?

Tags: java, variables, loops, for-loop

Before this the user inputs an int for numOfTimes. Say it's 5. This will ask the question 5 times. But each time through it will erase the previous value in hrs1. It needs to be a separate variable. So if numOfTimes=5 Then I should get 5 different doubles for "Hour "  and 5 different doubles for "Minute ". (assuming the user inputs different times) but they all need to be stored in different variables. How should I do this?

Thank you my question has been answered!

Comment: You need a List. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html, or an array (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). A List has the advantage of not having a fixed size, so you can loop as many times as you want, until the user decides to stop, for example.

Comment: You can use an Array. Read more http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: wat is the issue in existing ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put your "calculate average" code outside the for loop. I am not sure exactly how you want to calculate the average. But here are two simple ways.

Method one - keep track of the totals and calculate the basic average.

```
public class AvgTime {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.print("How many times? ");
    int numOfTimes = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("\n");

    double hrTotal = 0;
    double minTotal = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= numOfTimes; i++){

      System.out.println("What Time (military time):  ");
      System.out.print("Hour  ");
      double hrs1 = in.nextDouble();
      System.out.print("Minute  ");
      double min1 = in.nextDouble();

      hrTotal += hrs1;
      minTotal += min1;
    }

    //calculate average
    double avdHr1 = hrTotal/numOfTimes;
    double timeMin1 = minTotal/numOfTimes;

    System.out.println(avgHr1+":"+timeMin1 + " P.M");
  }
}
```

Method 2 - Use lists and iterate twice

public class AvgTime {

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.print("How many times? ");
    int numOfTimes = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("\n");

    ArrayList<Double> hours = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Double> minutes = new ArrayList<>();
    double minTotal = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= numOfTimes; i++){

      System.out.println("What Time (military time):  ");
      System.out.print("Hour  ");
      double hrs1 = in.nextDouble();
      System.out.print("Minute  ");
      double min1 = in.nextDouble();

      hours.add(hrs1);
      minutes.add(min1);
    }

    //calculate average
    double avgHr1 = 0;
    double timeMin1 = 0:
    for (int i = 0; i < hours.size(); i++) {
      double hour = hours.get(i);
      double minute = minutes.get(i);

      //ToDo: calculate average so far

    }

    System.out.println(avgHr1+":"+timeMin1 + " P.M");
  }
```

Comment: Thank you this has helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

use an array ..

```
int a[] = new int[5];
for(int i =0;i<5;i++){
    a[i] = //your value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrays to store the information the user has input. Before the loop, make an array using the `new` keyword, e.g. `double[] hrs=new double[numOfTimes]`. In the loop, write to different locations in the array for each input, `hrs[i]=in.nextDouble()`.  You can later read from a position on the array using the syntax 'name[index]', such as 'hrs[2]'.  Note that for java and many other languages, arrays start at 0.  This means for an array [1,2,3] named arr, `arr[1]` equals 2 instead of 1.  This means it would be best if your for loop was changed from `for(int i=1;i<=numofTimes;i++)` to 'for(int i=0;i

Answer (score 0):

`<SOAPBOX,RANT,HIGHHORSE>`

This is more of a code review than a straight answer, but something has been bugging me about newbie questions that I've observed on stackoverrflow.

When developing, I avoid keyboard input like the plague. It is such drudgery, especially with a loop such as in this program. So many newbie questions have user-keyboard input. Why?! It makes development so much more difficult!

I've rewritten your program to add the ability for testing data, completely avoiding the need for user-input during development. When testing is over, just switch the test/live comments around.

I'm sure there's a more elegant way, but this style has worked well for me, and I recommend it.

`</SOAPBOX,RANT,HIGHHORSE>`

```
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.Math.abs;

public class AverageTimeWTestingData  {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      HourMin24[] ahm = null;

      //EXACTLY ONE of the following lines must be commented out
      //Test only:
         ahm = getTestData();
      //Live only:
      // ahm = getDataFromUserInput();

      double dTotalHours = 0.0;
      for (HourMin24 hm : ahm){
         System.out.println("Time: " + hm.iHour + ":" + hm.iMin);
         dTotalHours += hm.iHour + (hm.iMin / 60);
      }

      System.out.println("Average time (" + ahm.length + "): " + (dTotalHours / ahm.length));
   }
   private static final HourMin24[] getDataFromUserInput()  {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("How many times? ");
      int numOfTimes = in.nextInt();
      ArrayList<HourMin24> al24 = new ArrayList<HourMin24>(numOfTimes);
      while(numOfTimes < 0)  {
         System.out.println("What Time (military time):  ");
         System.out.print("Hour  ");
         int iHour = in.nextInt();
         System.out.print("Minute  ");
         int iMin = in.nextInt();

         al24.add(new HourMin24(iHour, iMin));

         numOfTimes--;
      }

      return  al24.toArray(new HourMin24[al24.size()]);
   }
   private static final HourMin24[] getTestData()  {
      System.out.println("TEST MODE ON");
      return  new HourMin24[] {
         new HourMin24(13, 1),
         new HourMin24(23, 19),
         new HourMin24(0, 59),
         new HourMin24(16, 16),
      };
   }
}
class HourMin24  {
   public int iHour;
   public int iMin;
   public HourMin24(int i_hour, int i_min)  {
      iHour = i_hour;
      iMin = i_min;
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java AverageTimeWTestingData
TEST MODE ON
Time: 13:1
Time: 23:19
Time: 0:59
Time: 16:16
Average time (4): 13.0
```